# Using VBA to remove the reference to a file name in formulas

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to copy a series of worksheets from an Excel workbook and paste them into a new workbook. The issue that I am having is that when I copy worksheets into a new workbook the formulas still a reference to the old workbook in the formulas. I tried to get the name of the workbook and replace it with a null character but I believe my code is referencing the new workbook and not the old one. I tried a function as well as 'ThisWorkbook' as well as 'ActiveWorkbook' but none seem to be working.

Here is the function....

```
Function MyName() As String
    MyName = ThisWorkbook.Name
End Function
```

Here is the full code....

```
Sub CopyToNewWorkbook()

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
  Dim wbName As Variant
  Dim wbNew As Workbook

  'wbName = ActiveWorkbook.Name
  'wbName = ThisWorkbook.Name
  Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

  For Each ws In wbCurrent.Sheets   
    Do While wbNew.Sheets.Count <= (wbCurrent.Sheets.Count - 3)
      For i = 3 To wbCurrent.Sheets.Count
        wbCurrent.Sheets(i).Copy after:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)            
      Next i
    Loop            
  Next ws

  wbNew.Activate
  Sheets("Sheet1").Select
  ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

  Cells.Replace What:=MyName, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry I don't have time to type up the code but...if you replace all of the =(equal) signs with a | (pipe) before copying, all of the formulas will be converted to a text string.  You can then copy the worksheets to the new workbook, do a find and replace for the workbook name on the new sheets, finally do a find and replace for the | back to = and you're all done.

Comment: Your 3 loops are somehow redundant, no?  Belt and suspender?

Comment: It would probably help if you showed some examples of what these formulas look like, presently.

Comment: @Vincent G, yes you are correct I have several loops and I believe the problem that I am having is getting back to the original file or differentiating between the two.

Comment: @BWMustang13 Only the inner For loop is necessary, the other two are of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get the intended results with the following code.

```
  Sub CopyToNewWorkbook()      

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim wbCurrent As Workbook
  Dim wbName As Variant
  Dim wbNew As Workbook

  Call MyName
    wbName = MyName

  Set wbCurrent = ActiveWorkbook
  Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add

  For Each ws In wbCurrent.Sheets   
    ws.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Do While wbNew.Sheets.Count <= (wbCurrent.Sheets.Count - 3)
      For i = 3 To wbCurrent.Sheets.Count
        wbCurrent.Sheets(i).Copy after:=wbNew.Sheets(wbNew.Sheets.Count)            
      Next i
    Loop            
  Next ws

  wbNew.Activate
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
      ActiveWindow.SelectedSheets.Delete

  Cells.Replace What:=MyName, Replacement:="", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

  Cells.Replace What:="'[" & wbName & "]", Replacement:="'", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post answers to your own question. Instead, update the question with a "SOLUTION" section.

Comment: @ScottMarcus Where it is requested to do so? http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer doesn't mention that.

Answer (score 0):

Could you not just use the BreakLinks method?

```
'Get all links
  ExternalLinks = wbNew.LinkSources(Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks)

'Break each link
 For x = 1 To UBound(ExternalLinks)
   wbNew.BreakLink Name:=ExternalLinks(x), Type:=xlLinkTypeExcelLinks
 Next x
```

Comment: breaking those links will break the formulas altogether and keep values?

Comment: Yes. Breaking the links breaks the formulas, which I do not want to do.

Comment: Sorry if I've misunderstood the requirement there. So are you saying you want the formula in each cell that references the old book to be changed,  replacing the name of the old book with that of the new?